# Округление значения поля с шагом в 0.5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Есть числовое поле с установленным минимальным и максимальным значениями и шагом в 0.5. Подскажите пожалуйста, как округлять введенные значения в соответствии с шагом.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" placeholder="1">
```

Comment: Что значит "округлять"? Выводить не "1", а "1.0"?

Comment: а если шаг будет 0.3, то как надо округлять?

Comment: @lexxl, до 0.5, я думаю

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, это значит, если пользователь ввел 0.3 - округлить до 0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type = number]');
var inputValue;
var decimal = 1;

input.addEventListener('change', function(e){
 
  if(e.target.value % 1 == 0){
   decimal = 0;
  } else {
   decimal = 1;
  }

  inputValue = (Math.round(e.target.value * 2) / 2).toFixed(decimal);
  e.target.value = inputValue;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" placeholder="1">
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ. Существует ли вариант сделать так, чтобы при введенном целом числе, функция не обрабатывала его чтобы по окончанию `change` значение не округлялось, т.е. не получало `,0` в конце целого числа?

Comment: Добавил ваше пожелание в ответ)

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь)